# How to safely use Google translate in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I am into a project which requires translating text from different languages to English . In a day , I would have to translate nearly 5000 documents.I have written a small selenium code that would help me translate these documents.

Now my question is that if i use Selenium for translating a huge data from google translate ,will I be blocked by Google . If yes , what is the solution to avoid being blocked by Google Translate ?

I have posted my code below for reference :

```
public static WebDriver google_translate(WebDriver driver,String filename)
    {

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5
                , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        try{
        driver.get("http://translate.google.com/#auto/en");    
        String text="";         
        text=read_contents.read_from_html(filename);
        if(text.length()<5)
            return driver ;
        // Enter the query string "Cheese"
        System.out.println("file read");
        WebElement query = driver.findElement(By.id("source"));
        query.sendKeys(text);
        WebElement query1 = driver.findElement(By.id("gt-submit"));
        query1.click();
        System.out.println("text entered");
        Date d=new Date();
        long intial=d.getTime();
        WebElement result;
        do{
            result = driver.findElement(By.id("result_box"));
            d=new Date();
        }while(result.getText().length()<20 && (d.getTime()-intial<15000) );
        System.out.println("result fetched");
        String output=Global.prop.get(1).toString()+"/"+new File(filename).getName()+".txt";
        output_writer.txt_writer(result.getText(),output);
        }
        catch(UnhandledAlertException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(NoSuchElementException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(UnknownServerException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //System.out.println(result.getText());    
        return driver ;
```

Comment: If you get blocked I would recommend using a service that allows this amount of text to be posted.

Comment: Can you suggest some Alternatives ? I had tried the Google Translate API . But they are way to expensive for daily usage!

Comment: A simple search would get you that kiran: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6151668/alternative-to-google-translate-api